# Community Clip alternatives software for windows 10

Tags: video-editing, screen-recording, windows-10

I have installed the latest version of **Community Clip but it is not working with windows 10.**

Please suggest me **free & the best screen recorders similar to community clip and from genuine software provider company without any spyware**.

I have tried **“Screecast-O-matic”** and **“Camtasia”** but they are paid and also not as faster as Community clip.

I use to record my screen in windows 8.1 using community clip and it has great benefits like video size is low with HD and also directly save video in .mp4 format.

**“Screecast-O-matic” and “Camtasia” takes longer time to save video in .mp4**

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.